# SQL Server 2008 Replication Promotion

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a 4 node cluster, 1 subscriber and 3 publishers, all running SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. The intention is that if the subscriber goes down, we can use one of the publishers to quickly build up its replacement. Our testing reveals a problem though: the subcriber databases all have `Not For Replication` set to `Yes` on the identity columns so that they can maintain the identity set in the subscriber. This causes a problem when *they* become subscribers because now we don't have identity insert functionality: we get a primary key error. Any way to "promote" a subscriber to publisher?

Comment: Apparent DBCC CHECKIDENT offers some ability to reseed the identity column.

Comment: Are you looking to have this subscriber promted to publisher automatic when there is a fail over detected?

Comment: No, I'd just like to fix the identity problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at something like this: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1274

You could prepare scripts needed before hand and if your publisher goes down you can have all the scripts ready before hand to build up the replacement.